# What is a good way to stop 2 labels in the same row and column from covering each other in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

When button 1 is pressed I want this program to say word 'hi' and when button 2 is pressed I want it to say 'goodbye' in the same spot as it says hi and override what button 1 produced. However, it doesn't override it just merges the 2 labels together. What is a good way to prevent this from happening while making sure both labels appear in the same spot?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def press():
    word = Label(root, text='hi')
    word.grid(row=0, column=1)

def press_2():
    word_2 = Label(root, text='goodbye')
    word_2.grid(row=0, column=1)


button_1 = Button(root, text=1, command=press)
button_2 = Button(root, text=2, command=press_2)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use one `Label` and keep changing its text. We can do this efficiently by using a `lambda` for the widget `command`. As stated by @Bryan Oakley, using a `StringVar` adds unnecessary overhead. This is a slightly modified version from my original. In this version we use the `config` method of the widget to set the text. As a *bonus* the code is formatted with a class structure. Using a procedural style with `tkinter` eventually turns into a big mess. Considering the required imports are minimal, we import them directly and do not need to prefix every widget.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        
        lbl = Label(self, text='hi')
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)
        
        btn1 = Button(self, text='1',)
        btn1.config(command=lambda m='hi': lbl.config(text=m))
        btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        btn2 = Button(self, text='2')
        btn2.config(command=lambda m='goodbye': lbl.config(text=m))
        btn2.grid(row=1, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.minsize(100, 50)
    app.title("My Application")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would argue that the _best_ way is to directly change the label without using a `StringVar`.

Comment: Yeah, for a `Label` you're probably right. I probably should have used `theLabel.config(text="someValue")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def press():
    label['text'] = "hi"

def press_2():
    label['text'] = "goodbye"


label = Label(root)
label.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_1 = Button(root, text=1, command=press)
button_2 = Button(root, text=2, command=press_2)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Put it on the windows firstly,Then change the `text` config.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do so would be by using `config()` method of widgets. But here i dont know if its gonna help out much. But give it a try

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def press():
    word.config(text='hi')


def press_2():
    word.config(text='goodbye')


button_1 = Button(root, text=1, command=press)
button_2 = Button(root, text=2, command=press_2)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
word = Label(root, text='') #creating a blank label to edit later on in functions
word.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```